# one word string to vector in R

Tags: r, string, vector

having a string like

```
"xzyyzyzyxyyyxxxyzzyzzzxzyxxzzzyzyxyxxxxyxxyxxyxyyzxyzzyzzxyxyyzxzzxyxxyxxzyxyzyxzzyzxxyzyzyyyzxxxzxx"
```

How can I convert it to a vector like:

```
"x","z","y","y","z","y","z","y","x","y","y","y","x","x","x","y","z","z","y","z","z","z","x","z","y","x","x","z","z","z","y","z","y","x",","y",","x","x","x","x",","y",","x","x",","y",","x","x",","y",","x","y","y","z","x","y","z","z","y","z","z","x",","y",","x","y","y","z","x","z","z","x",","y",","x","x",","y",","x","x","z","y","x","y","z","y","x","z","z","y","z","x","x","y","z","y","z","y","y","y","z","x","x","x","z","x","x"
```

I can not do

```
unlist(strsplit("thestring", split=""))
```

Comment: Why you `can not do`?

Comment: You may have a typo. Try `strsplit(thestring, split="")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
strsplit("xzyyzyzyxyyyxxxyzzyzzzxzyxxzzzyzyxyxxxxyxxyxxyxyyzxyzzyzzxyxyyzxzzxyxxyxxzyxyzyxzzyzxxyzyzyyyzxxxzxx", "")
[[1]]
[1] "x" "z" "y" "y" "z" "y" "z" "y" "x" "y" "y" "y" "x" "x" "x" "y" "z" "z" "y" "z" "z" "z" "x" "z" "y" "x" "x" "z" "z" "z" "y" "z" "y" "x" "y" "x" "x" "x" "x"
[40] "y" "x" "x" "y" "x" "x" "y" "x" "y" "y" "z" "x" "y" "z" "z" "y" "z" "z" "x" "y" "x" "y" "y" "z" "x" "z" "z" "x" "y" "x" "x" "y" "x" "x" "z" "y" "x" "y" "z"
[79] "y" "x" "z" "z" "y" "z" "x" "x" "y" "z" "y" "z" "y" "y" "y" "z" "x" "x" "x" "z" "x" "x"
```

To assign to a new vector:

```
x <- strsplit("xzyyzyzyxyyyxxxyzzyzzzxzyxxzzzyzyxyxxxxyxxyxxyxyyzxyzzyzzxyxyyzxzzxyxxyxxzyxyzyxzzyzxxyzyzyyyzxxxzxx", "")
str(x)
#List of 1
# $ : chr [1:100] "x" "z" "y" "y" ...
is.vector(x)
#[1] TRUE
```

If you would like to use `thestring` as the name of the object, it would have to be done in similar fashion:

```
thestring <- "xzyyzyzyxyyyxxxyzzyzzzxzyxxzzzyzyxyxxxxyxxyxxyxyyzxyzzyzzxyxyyzxzzxyxxyxxzyxyzyxzzyzxxyzyzyyyzxxxzxx"
strsplit(thestring, "")
```

Note that you can also save this output as another object:

```
thestring2 <- strsplit(thestring, "")
#You can 'rename' the same object too, bear in mind you would have to assign the actual "xzyy..." to `thestring` first:
thestring <- strsplit(thestring, "")
```

Comment: how to assign that to a vector

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html

Comment: I have edited the answer with some more information @cMinor